# php Carbon lang error in spanish

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to show some Carbon in Spanish but it's not working. Can anybody please help me and tell me why it doesn't. 1 is showing in English.

This one appears in English: (Friday 06 October 2017)

```
{{ Carbon::parse($biz->payment_next)->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y') }}
```

This works and appears in spanish:

```
{{ Carbon::parse($biz->payment_next)->diffForHumans() }}
```

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using this package jenssegers/date, it helps with this problem

Answer (score 1):

you should change the language

example:

```
Carbon::setLocale('es');
```

the docs:

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but is already specified <?php setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es'); Carbon::setLocale('es'); ?>

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the locale you want to format:

```
Carbon::setLocale('es');
```

And since your language is not regular ASCII, is better to format enabling UTF8 encode before formatting:

```
Carbon::setUTF8(true);
```